# Google Maps position inside Bootstrap modal is always off by the map size width and height

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, google-maps, google-maps-markers

First things first, here's a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/WppF6/168/

When I launch the map inside the modal, it's always off down and to the right by the size of the pixels of the window (300x300). If you then scroll up and to the left, you'll see the marker there - basically it's not centered as it should.

The coordinates are correct and it works FINE if it's OUTSIDE a modal.

I assume it has to do with the div loading before the map is loaded or something and it then centering wrong, but I can't figure out why that is. I tried to put this at the end of the code but it didn't work:

```
$("#myModal").on("shown.bs.modal", function () {
               google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
});
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Here is how it should look like:

[image]

And how it's wrong:

[image]

Note that the coordinates are not always the same, so if there's a solution that doesn't require the coordinates to re-center the map (or load it the appropriate size in the first place) that would be preferred.

Comment: Edit the Zoom level or the center ?

Answer (score 2):

I had somewhat of a similar problem except my problem was to do with multiple points. Try firing this up after initializing the map.

```
var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapProp);
map.fitBounds(new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
    new google.maps.LatLng(lat-50, lng-50),
    new google.maps.LatLng(lat+50, lng+50)
));
```

Here lat and lng are your co ordinates. What it does is it focuses the map according to the bounds given. The first parameter is the left bottom corner and the next one is the right top corner.

Answer (score 1):

you can save the center point to a variable and set it when the modal fires

```
map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
      center = results[0].geometry.location;
```

then

```
$("#myModal").on("shown.bs.modal", function () {
           google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
           map.setCenter(center);
});
```

**see http://jsfiddle.net/k0odnn80/**